# Can I download a folder hierarchy full of Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, bulk-download

I have a folder on Google Drive full of Google Docs (i.e. the MS Word equivalent). I'd like to download all of these, exporting them to either MS Word or PDF. However, the only way I can find to do this is to open up each document individually and export it as Word. Is there a quicker way?

(I have the Google Drive client installed locally - this just provides .gdoc files which are links to the original in a browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by choosing the Google docs which ever you would like to download and then click the drop down list of the "More" button which is available in top of google drive page.

Now you can able to find  the option "Download" in that drop-down list. You can get a pop-up after once you click the option "Download". In that pop-up you can choose the formats as Ms Word or PDF and click download. It download as a zip file, once completed please extract it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I found I could also download a folder, which zips up the contents as MS documents automatically.